# -bash No such file or directory - How to remove?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, terminal

I tried to update Ruby on rails, but it seams like everything crashed. This is what I get when I open the terminal. What can I do to fix this?

```
-bash: /Users/pontuspersson/.rvm/scripts/rvm[[: No such file or directory
unknown0025003f3355:~ pontuspersson$
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your Bash profile/rc file got hosed up from the last step of the rvm install.

Try deleting the line and adding it again as per the installation instructions.

Barring that, you can always blow away rvm and start over; it's a pain time-wise, but not catastrophic.

Comment: Thanks Dave! How do I do that? I have read that I should have a .bash_profile file but I can not find one.

Comment: @user1104735 You should have either a `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` in your home directory.